# Pandas Series division by another Series with rounded upto 2 decimals before division

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have 2 series as follows:

```
a = | -780190.40 |
    | 5310187.20 |
    | 310227.60  |
    | 7388071.76 |
    | 2969833.52 |      

b = | 7524683.10 |
    | 3375071.76 |
    | 2930243.68 |
    | 97616826.24|
    | 11157575.12|
```

I want to create a sereis

```
'c'  = b.round(2) / a.round(2)
```

But 'c' still holds the values upto 4 decimal places. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? I want 'c' to have values rounded upto 2 decimals.

Comment: Why do you want to round before the division? Round the result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
In [2151]: a = pd.Series([-780190.40, 5310187.20, 310227.60])    
In [2152]: b = pd.Series([7524683.10, 3375071.76, 2930243.68])

In [2155]: c = round(b/a)    
In [2156]: c 
Out[2156]: 
0   -10.00
1     1.00
2     9.00
dtype: float64
```